# Display increments of bubblesort in android studio

Tags: android

I would like to display an increment of the bubblesort per listview  by appending and adding string builder under a nested loop. However, my code prints outs all the steps from the previous step

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();




    List<Integer>myList = newActivity.list;
    int listAmt = newActivity.list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < listAmt-1; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < listAmt - i - 1; j++) {


            for (int k = 0; k < listAmt - i; k++) {
                    builder.append(myList.get(k));
                    builder.append("  ");
                }


            if (myList.get(j) > myList.get(j + 1)) {
                int temp = myList.get(j);
                myList.set(j, myList.get(j + 1)); //swaps position of j with j+1
                myList.set(j + 1, temp);


            }
                list.add(builder.toString());
            }




    }
```

Where do i add the builder to prevent this from happening?

Comment: ie if i enter 2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8, the output is "2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 " then "2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" ...... until loop ends